# extract text from image using asprise ocr

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ocr

I am trying to get text from image using Aspires OCR. But I am getting an error on

```
OCR().recognizeCharacters((RenderedImage) image)
```

To resolve this issue in need `com.asprise.util.ocr.OCR` jar file, but could not find this jar anywhere. so please tell me the site or link where from I can get this jar or tell me another way to get text from image.

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.asprise.ocr.*;
public class ReadImage {
    WebDriver driver;   
    @Test
    public void test(){
        Ocr.setUp();
        Ocr ocr=new Ocr();
        ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST);
        String imagePath = "D:\\Img\\PLPServlet.jpg";
        driver.get("file:///D:/Img/image.html");
        String path = driver.findElement(By.id("img")).getAttribute("src");
        URL url = new URL(path);
        Image image = ImageIO.read(url);
        System.out.println("image 'SRC' is = " +image);
        String s = new OCR().recognizeCharacters((RenderedImage) image);
        System.out.println("Text From Image : \n"+s);  

    }
}
```

Comment: google -> https://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-for-windows-mac-linux-download.html

Answer (score 0):

Yo can find the libs in maven repository - Do a mvn search to find similar library.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.asprise.ocr/java-ocr-api/15.3.0.3